# Devise: using devise instance variables in non-devise controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, instance-variables

Devise provides `current_user` (and apparently `@current_user` as the underlying instance variable of `current_user`) but it also has a variable called: `@minimum_password_length`. I'd like to have access to this as I have created a reusable partial `_user_fields.html.erb` that shows some password requirements to the user based on the value (or even its even provided). This particular variable gets set through the `config.password_length` configuration in `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.

Is there a way to get access to Devise instance variables outside of the controllers it oversees? And if this is possible, +1 to anyone who can link me to documentation on all the Devise instance variables you can access outside of Devise controllers.

Comment: Does `Devise.password_length.min` work for you? [Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L119) All the lines that stated `mattr_accessor` are accessible via `Devise.method_name` so I guess that would be your "Documentation"? But [This](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise) probably counts too

Comment: @engineersmnky yes that works!

Comment: Also @mridula's deleted answer also worked. I would've given her the rep for it, too bad she deleted it for some reason.